# In what situation would normal choke packet be preferred over hop-by-hop choke packets?

Tags: router, network, congestion

When the host is far away, it makes sense to use hop-by-hop choke packets to resolve congestion.
But is there situations where normal choke packet is more appropriate?

And by the 'source' we mean a sending router correct? If so, how does the PC connected to the source router react to choke packets?

Answer (score 1):

"Choke packets" haven't been a thing for some time.

ICMP *source quench* packets were deprecated in 1995 by RFC 1812, some 27 years ago. Source quench packets were originally intended to be sent by an in-path router, but could also be sent by the end host.